# Function running only after tkinter windows has been closed

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I'm learning how to program in Python and use the PIL (Pillow) in order to create small bots which can recognize changes in the screen in order to execute repetitive commands (keyboard presses with pynput module).

I did a small GUI with Tkinter in order to get user information regarding the parameters which the user is going to use (Entry widgets) at their use of the bot and I also need a few buttons for enabling/disabling certain parts of the code (i'm using check buttons and using boolean logic in order to enable/disable) and also for enabling the main function of the bot (which is to press a button once it recognizes a certain change at the screen).

What I am currently experiencing is that the once I run my program, it opens up my GUI and all that a user would see but it doesn't execute my main function, it only executes the main function AFTER I close the GUI.
I'd love to post my code but it exceeds 220 lines and it would probably become even more confusing.

So, long story short, is it a kind of error which happens a lot when inexperienced programmers try to create softwares with tkinter? If yes, what causes it and how can it be fixed?

I appreciate any help you guys can get me. :]

```py
    ...creates frames, widgets, entries...

    mainHealerVar = IntVar() 
    main_healer_check = Checkbutton(root, text="Enable the bot", variable=mainHealerVar) #this should mean that when i press this checkbutton it'll enable the bot and perform the repetitive commands for as long as it stays checked

    ... some more buttons/code...


    root.mainloop() #right after I stop setting up the GUI, I place this function

    ... make logic in order to know which part of the repetitive functions to execute...

    if mainHealerVar.get() == 1:
        mainHealFunction()    #function to check if the checkbutton is still pressed (if it is, it should execute mainHealFunction()
```

It was supposed to execute the repetitive commands by the pynput module as soon as i clicked on the enabling Check-button, but it doesn't execute anything until I close the GUI, then it starts to execute the repetitive commands. I have also tried using a while loop instead of an "if" at the end, but ended up with the same result.

Comment: What you're missing is that a tk Python program pretty much *ends* at `root.mainloop()`: there might be some final clean-up code afterward, but all the action—the entire duration of the program—happens while `root.mainloop()` runs. Everything you do, you do as a consequence of the user clicking some button, or entering some text, or moving a mouse or window, or whatever, and each of those ops calls one of *your* functions—or, if you haven't thought of it, doesn't (and then your code isn't useful :-) ).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! For what I could understand from your answer you mean that I should put my root.mainloop() function at the very end of the code? I tried doing this earlier but then I get a NameError about a variable which I had declared as global earlier in the code, and then I can't run it.

Comment: Yes, essentially you create the setup, then call `root.mainloop()` to have everything run. Whatever the `NameError` issue is, that's a pure Python issue, rather than a tk thing.